# Accessing a MovieClip on script? (AS2)

Tags: flash, movieclip, actionscript-2

I'm used to working with AS3, but due to recent events I need to work with AS2, and I'm having trouble with a simple task:

**How do I access a MovieClip in AS?** I drew something, converted it to a symbol (of type MovieClip) and ticked "Export for ActionScript". I gave it the name "MyMC". now, when I'm in some other MovieClips action, how do I access the MovieClip I drew on stage before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an object on the stage you need to give it an instance name using the properties panel, and then you can access it through the `_root` property:

[image]

```
_root.myMc.doSomething();
```

---

**Use of Identifier:**

Telling a library symbol to export for actionscript works in a similar way to in AS3.  The export name you assign is a name that you use to create an instance of that symbol, using the `attachMovie` function:

```
var myMC:MovieClip = this.attachMovie("instanceName","MyMC",this.getNextHighestDepth());
```

`attachMovie` accepts 3 parameters:

1. **instanceName**: this is like the `name` property of a DisplayObject in AS3.  It is a unique name that you assign to each instance of the symbol you create.
2. **Library Identifier**: This is the name that you put into the Identifier field when creating the symbol.
3. **Depth**: The depth of this MovieClip on the display tree.  You can target a specific depth, or use `getNextHighestDepth` to place it in the highest available depth, same as using `addChild` in AS3.

Comment: When you say "instance name", you mean the "Identifier" text field, correct?

Comment: I tried doing what you said: I created 2 MCs, one called First and the other Second. I Exported both to AS and then put the following code in Second:
`on (press)
{
 trace(_root.First);
 trace(_root);
}`

When I press Second, the log output is:

undefined
_level0

Comment: If you have actually put `First` on the stage, you have to give it an instance name using the properties panel.  Identifiers are only useful when attaching symbols dynamically.